# Configuring an IdentityServer with B2C for secondary claims extension

Tags: identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c

We currently have B2C configured with an external Idp, users can log in and everything is working.

The difficulty is our customer wants to perform a claim extension after the user has logged in to fetch extra claims for a specific journey.

Our thinking is that we will use IdentityServer to act as a STS and then fetch extra claims

Both the app and the STS will be hosted by the same domain and both will be on https

Is it possible without changing the existing configuration to have the bearer token generated from the STS (and authenticated to the B2C) appear to be from the same provider.

Comment: Take a look at [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, using B2C for authentication and IdentityServer4 for STS. I add claims to the access_token (Bearer token) by implementing:

IProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync()

If you add there it ends up on the access_token. Not 100% sure that's the best place to be doing it but it works.

HTH